# Padding in tables that are not border="0"

Tags: html, css

With CSS, I'm trying to add 5px padding to tables which do not have the border attribute set to "0". To do this, I'm able to select these tables like this, and test it by making the background color of them red:

```
table:not([border="0"]),table:not([border="0"])>tr,table:not([border="0"])>tr>td
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also, this works to make all tables have padding:

```
td,th
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

However, I only want tables with borders to have padding, and this does not work:

```
table:not([border="0"]),table:not([border="0"])>tr,table:not([border="0"])>tr>td
{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Does anyone see an issue here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I see the code I posted above actually works, I didn't realize that I left out code that broke it, but this is what I tried to get working:

```
table:not([border="0"]),table:not([border="0"])>tr,table:not([border="0"])>tr>td
{
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

The `border-collapse:collapse;` property seems to be causing this problem. Is there any way to have single borders between cells and padding at the same time?

Comment: If I had control of the HTML, I would probably apply a CSS class to the tables instead of doing something like this. Although this probably works it, I prefer to only be clever like this when I have no other options.

Comment: Your code actually works as you expect, See Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/AHDYc/1/

Comment: I don't see how the code works without the added tbody (see my answer). Although the table itself gets padding, the cells don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<table>` always has a `<tbody>` if you don't specify one explicitly in the HTML.
(It would be different in XHTML, but this is HTML, not XHTML.)

Solution: also specify the tbody in the CSS selectors.

```css
table:not([border="0"]), table:not([border="0"])>tbody>tr, table:not([border="0"])>tbody>tr>td
{
  padding:15px;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/AHDYc/2/)

By the way, you could remove the middle selector (ending in `tr`) from the rule, because it doesn't do anything. You can't give padding to table rows.

You say it does work with the first example in your post, but that isn't entirely true. Only the first selector works, giving the whole table the red background, and the other two are ignored, so the cells remain transparent.

Oh, and it's best to not use the `border` attribute any more. There was a dispute between the WHATWG and the W3C about whether it was still valid, but they finally agreed that it was obsolete.